# SVG to PNG image conversion in php

Tags: php, imagick, image-conversion

I want to convert SVG images to PNG files with transparent background. I am using below code to convert it using imagick in php,but it gives image with black background.

```
        $image = new imagick();
        //set transparent background
        $image->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
        $image->setFormat('svg');
        $image->readImageBlob(file_get_contents("image.svg"));
        $image->setImageFormat("png32");
        $image->resizeImage(265,195, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
        $image->writeImage('result.png');
```

Can anyone please help me how to convert above svg image to png image using PHP.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check if ImageMagick is installed (you can find out using phpinfo).

Comment: If i had not installed imagemagick, how would i be able to convert it and get  black background image :(. Please provide other suggestions.