# imageMagick not working, to convert the SVG (SVG having mask image also) to PNG

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick, png, mask

I have tried to convert SVG to PNG image but it's not working,
Tested using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39661410/svg-to-png-image-conversion-in-php),
but it's creating the white image and if I used

`$image->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));` it created the black/transparent image

SVG image  : [SVG image actual view on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbO2q.png)
After converting: [SVG to PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reKO0.png)

SVG with mask : [Sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hNf39l4cnYhMLl1ZkvEeEBRgSPJic4VK/view)

Comment: Check it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809194/convert-svg-image-to-png-with-php

Comment: I have also tried the above code,  it didn't work with external image, In my case assets folder having the custom image with mask image:

Comment: Post a link to your actual SVG file.

Comment: I have added the my sample SVG file

Comment: @fmw42 could you please guide me more here ?

Comment: Your SVG file has a linked image, which cannot be found. It is linked to a local file at `assets/right.inside.mask.print.png` for the mask. If that file is not available, then it won't rasterize properly.

Comment: Thanks for reply @fmw42 
Yes both mask and image files are in assets folder with SVG file, does this means I need to give site URL with mask and custom image 

Please see the sample file with assests folder and try to open in browser for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given all your data downloaded to my computer, I can convert it to png using ImageMagick 6.9.10.82 Q16 Mac OSX Sierra that calls Inkscape 0.92.4 as the SVG renderer.

```
convert right.inside.svg x.png
```

[image]

You have not shown the correct result. So I do not know if this is correct or not. But it does appear to be correct given the images in the assets folder.

However, the mask and other image needs to be accessible from whomever is trying to view the svg file. So either the data needs to be downloaded or perhaps you need to provide the URL to those files on some server that has the svg file.

Comment: I am able to convert the SVG to PNG also SVG to PDF **thanks you** @fmw42

I have installed the inkScape on my server and it's working now: 
https://connectwww.com/how-to-install-inkscape-on-ubuntu-best-vector-graphics-editor/5581/